# Jquery Selector for dynamically created elements

Tags: php, jquery

I am creating html in PHP like here

```
<?php
while(){
  ?>
 <a  id="click_to_expand-1" class="btn btn-default btn-sm "> more</a>
 <div id="expand_content-1" class="row extra-detail-gist" style="display: none;">
      <ul class="extra-feature-gist">
          <li>
           <p><strong>Baths :</strong><span class="text-success"> <?php echo $rw["baths"]; ?></span></p>
          </li>
      </ul>
<?php
}
?>
```

Here is my Jquery code

```
$(function(){
        $('.row.extra-detail-gist').css('display','none');
        $('.btn.btn-default.btn-sm').click(function(){
            $('.row.extra-detail-gist').slideToggle('slow');
            $(this).toggleClass('slideSign');
            return false;
        });
    });
```

This code apply for all div created and all divs are showing at click.How can i differenciate for each click on 'more'?

**UPDATED**:
This code is working for first one properly..but rest of the records are not working

```
$(function(){
        $('#expand_content-1').css('display','none');
        $('#click_to_expand-1').click(function(){
            $('#expand_content-1').slideToggle('slow');
            $(this).toggleClass('slideSign');
            return false;
        });
});
```

Here is [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/b1k5ak9c/)

Comment: not sure what the issue is, but judging from the title I'd assume you want  $('.btn.btn-default.btn-sm').on('click', function(){ if you are wanting to bind to dynamically created elements

Comment: `$(this).next('.row.extra-detail-gist').slideToggle('slow');`. By the way, `$('.row.extra-detail-gist').css('display','none');` can be `$('.row.extra-detail-gist').hide();`. Moreover, since all elements are hidden by default (`style="display: none;")`, this line is useless.

Comment: Actually the loop creates <a> and div with same class....for example there are 6 recordds so all have same class...when i click on first one it also apply on remaining

Comment: It's not gonna work with `ID` selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

**Working [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/b1k5ak9c/1/)**

```
$(document).on('click','.btn.btn-default.btn-sm',function(){
    $(this).parent().next('.row.extra-detail-gist').slideToggle('slow');
    $(this).toggleClass('slideSign');
    return false;
});
```

With this line `$('.row.extra-detail-gist')` you are selecting all the `divs` which has `row extra-detail-gist` class.

Comment: One more important thing: it has to be `,`, not `.` after `'click'`. By the way, `$('.btn.btn-default.btn-sm').on('click', function() {` looks better for me (since there are no dynamically created elements).